# Отладка visual studio 2013

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет. При пошаговой отладке любого проекта вылезает ошибка:
"Код не выполняется.
В текущем потоке в данный момент не выполняется код, или не удалось получить стек вызовов"
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Опишите последовательность действий, которая приводит к такому поведению.

Answer (score 1):

У меня такая проблема возникла после установки Касперского Free. Причем добавлял в исключения все, что только можно, но не удалось избавиться от проблемы пока не удалил Касперского. (С Авастом работает, до Касперского был drWeb - работало).